# R doesn't generate button

Tags: android

I've just finished to do the layout I want, and even although I saved everything, when I try to find by id the button, the button I'm looking for is missing.. Both the button's I have.. I've checked in the R class, under the ID, and it seems it doesn't sees' the buttons. Doesn't generate them? I dunno.. Any way, it happens every time I use relative layout!! Is there any connection? It works with TableLayout and with linear layout.. Only with relative layout it make's problems.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/Background" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/corpTag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/corpTag"
    android:textColor="@color/White" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addBusinessButton"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="208dp"
    android:text="@string/addYourBusiness" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/searchBusinessButton"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addBusinessButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addBusinessButton"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:text="@string/searchBusiness" />
```

Comment: Try to clean the project

Comment: No there is no problem with relativelayout i think you should clean your project if you are using eclipse and again try to build it.

Comment: Are you even closing the `RelativeLayout` with `</RelativeLayout>`?

Comment: Removed the `R` tag, since this isn't related to the statistical language `R`. I think you might be looking for the  `r.js` or `r.java-file` tag?

Comment: Not r.js, that's for javascript. r.java-file is the one, but it isn't very meaningful to tag it that way for this case.

Comment: Also, make sure you don't have the line `import android.R;` in your imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem isn't related to relative layout, but is actually set on the background because Android drwable is case-sensitive and now allows you any capital letters for image or layout. Rename your image name or drwable name to "background" instead of Background."

Here is the problem with set background name:

```
android:background="@drawable/Background"
```

Comment: ishu, just wanted to let you know if you come this way that @Jamal has been reformatting your old answers. I don't know if he tried to inform you, but I want to make sure you know about this. I approved of a few of his edits, so you might want to look through his changes and try to adapt a new approach towards formatting your own answers.

Comment: Thanks, @AndrasDeak!  I'm still looking over more of them.  They still seem to have the same issues: improper formatting and excessive capitalization.

Comment: @Jamal, OK, just make sure that you don't step on the toes of ishu. This is my main concern with your serial edits (well, and that you edit posts which are a few years old, but I can understand why they bug you).

Answer (score 1):

I found this happening to me with a broken layout. No need to be worry. I am trying my best to giving you the solution

**Solution**

Make sure that anything the **R.** links to is not broken. Fix all errors in your XML files. If anything in the ADKs are broken, R will not regenerate.

If you somehow hit something and created import android.R in your activity, remove it.
Run **Project -> Clean.** This will delete and regenerate R and BuildConfig.

Make sure **Project -> Build** Automatically is ticked. If not, build it manually via **Menu -> Project -> Build Project .**

Wait a few seconds for the errors to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the Android Style ButtonBar. It isn't available for every API level. So if you have a low minSDK, it's not going to build and Eclipse/IntelliJ should give you an error message in its error pane.

The rule given by Google, is that you should always define your own resources. If you want to use a resource that is in the Android name space, that's fine, but you should copy it first and package it with your apk, because that's the only way you can be assured that it will always be bundled with your application.

And yes, I realize many people and many tutorials on the web don't do it that way, but that's because most people are lazy.